# Some concepts for finding CFG or finite state automata

Tags: automata, formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar, finite-automata

1. Given the information that L is a context-free language, is there any case that there is no algorithm to construct a context-free grammar for L? Any example?
2. Given the information that L is a regular language, is there any case that there is no algorithm to construct a finite state automata for L? Any example?

Comment: Isn't a context-free language a language that is generated by a context-free grammar?

Comment: Yes.  a context free language is a language generated by a context free grammar. But if you are not given a context free grammar for L and given the information that a language L is context free, can we find an algorithm to construct a context free grammar for L in every case?

Answer (score 3):

Given a recursively enumerable language $L$ and the information that $L$ is  *regular* [resp. *context-free*, *context-sensitive*, *recursive*], there is no algorithm to construct a *finite automaton* [resp. a *context-free grammar*, a *context sensitive grammar*, a [*total Turing machine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_that_always_halts)] for $L$.

Let $A$ be an alphabet and let $u, v \in A^*$. Then $u$ is said to be a *superword* of $v$ if there exist some words $u_0, \ldots, u_n, v_1, \ldots, v_n$ such that $v = v_1 \cdots v_n$ and $u = u_0v_1u_1v_2 \cdots v_nu_n$. For instance, $caccbaca$ is a superword of $abc$. Given a language $L$ on $A^*$,
let $S(L)$ be the language of all words that are superwords of some word in $L$. 
The following result is an easy consequence of the fact, due to Higman [1], that the order on $A^*$ defined by $u \leqslant v$ iff $v$ is a superword of $u$, is a well-quasi-order.

**Theorem**. For each language $L$, $S(L)$ is a regular language.

Now, if $A$ is nonempty, there is no algorithm that, given a recursively enumerable language $L$, computes a total Turing machine (and hence of course, a finite automaton) for $S(L)$. Otherwise, one would be able to decide whether $S(L) = A^*$, which is equivalent to decide whether $L$ contains the empty word. But by [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), this property is undecidable.

[1] G. Higman, Ordering by divisibility in abstract algebras. *Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society* **2** (1952) 326–336.